# Repositiory TextEdit Autocomplete

Tags: c#, winforms, repository, devexpress, text-editor

I hav a repository TextEdit And Repository Button Edit in NavBar of Devex. I want to set AutoComplete Source of any one of them. Is there anyway i can accomplish that.

Please Help Me. Thanx in Advance

Note: I am using Devex in WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

For the AutoComplete feature, you need to use [ComboBoxEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsComboBoxEdittopic). The [ComboBoxEdit.Properties.AutoComplete](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemComboBox_AutoCompletetopic) property enables it.